# Insert em banco postgres com Python

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sql-insert, dbase

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com o código abaixo e não estou conseguindo solucionar o problema... eu quero pegar várias linhas de insert e aplicar de uma vez só no banco de dados... e rodando esse código tem o seguinte erro: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
​

````
dados =  '\''+ df['codigo_filhos'] + '\'' +', ' + '\''+ + df['codigo_pai'] + '\'' + ');'
script = '''insert into bigbox.gestao_precos (codigo_filhos, codigo_pai) values (select ''' 
query = script + dados
##query.to_csv('teste.csv', sep = ';')
##query
cur.execute(query)
con.commit()  ```
````

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Para prosseguir com a postagem dentro do objetivo do site e facilitar a detecção do problema é importante você editar sua pergunta e fornecer um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) da tentativa no lugar do código apresentado. Para entender melhor que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e ter uma solução mais rápido vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](htt

Comment: Veja na [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) sobre `to_sql()`

Answer (score -3):

Encontrei essa pergunta no Stack Overflow e ajudaram com várias soluções: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query

Ao final da página tem uma solução utilizando o "executemany" e o código é parecido com o seu. Espero que ajude!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).